# discord.py How to get a server the bot is in with the most members

Tags: discord, discord.py

I wanted to know if there was a way to get a server with the most members that the bot is in. So like for example if the bot was in servers, a, b, c, and d, And server A had the most members, how can I make it show that it's the biggest server.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: So far couldn't think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this will be a command. Here is a sample code to answer your prompt:

```py
@bot.command() # your client/bot variable. IDK which you have so I put bot.
async def biggest_server(ctx):
    guilds = {len(guild.members):guild for guild in bot.guilds}
    max_members, max_guild = max(guilds.items())
    await ctx.send(f"{max_guild.name} is the biggest server I am in! They have {max_members} members!")
```

**Quick Documentation Links:**

- [`bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds) - Get the guilds that the bot is in. I use dictionary comprehension so that the guild object and it's member length stay paired.
- [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) - Get the maximum number of members (index 0). This returns the tuple of the biggest server. I unpack it to two variables.